# benefits of using directoryperdb in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have found out that there is an option directoryperdb but what are the benefits of using that instead of default file organization?

cheers,
/Marcin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main benefit is being able to mount different volumes per database.

Comment: And to reduce the number of files in each directory... but that would mean you have a whole lot of data.